# java nested for loops to get numbers triangle

Tags: java, nested-loops

my output should look like in image 1, but my output looks like in image 2.

I am not suppose to print out ... there I have to print out same thing with 32 then 64. int 
That is what i have so far, I got half of the triangle correct. I don't know how to reverse it though.

```
    k = 1;
    int j;
    int l = 1;
    for(int i=1; i <= 8; i++){
      for(j=8; j>i; j--){
        System.out.print("  ");
      }
      for(j=1; j<=k; j=j*2){
        System.out.print(j + " ");
      }
      for (j = 1; j<k; j=j*2) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");

        }

        k = k * 2;



      System.out.println();

    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you want me to google 100000 answers for you?

Comment: @KickButtowski I could not find any :(

Comment: @KickButtowski I have been working on this for like 3 days...now I am totally confused. My brain can't function well. I wish you could just explain how it should be done. That would helpful.

Comment: so.... what have you done, what have you tried, where do you think the problem is? seems like you have a homework (actually your image SHOWS it's a homework) that you want us to do for you. This is NOT what Stack Overflow is for, sorry

Comment: @ChhetriCamy did you see the possible duplicate link. I just copied and pasted your question title and I found what you want.

Comment: "HELP ME OUT!!!" is a good way to not get help. We are here to help out of joy not out of demand.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, in the 2nd loop, you still go from `j=1 -> k`. You can simply do a `k -> 1` loop to get a reversed sequence.

Also java has `printf` method, you may want to take a look..

Some example codes:

```
   int rows = 8;
    for (int r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
        System.out.print(new String(new char[rows - r]).replace("\0", "  "));
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++) 
            System.out.printf("%s%s", 1<<i, r == 0?  "\n" : " ");            
        if (r > 0) 
            for (int i = r-1; i >= 0; i--) 
                System.out.printf("%s%s", 1<<i, i == 0?  "\n" : " ");

    }
```

just adjust the `rows` to the value you like.

I did a test with `rows=8`, it prints:

```
                1
              1 2 1
            1 2 4 2 1
          1 2 4 8 4 2 1
        1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
      1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
    1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
  1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: I can't use printf right now. Thank you so much.